# How can I use the jQuery version of TinyMCE with GZIP compression?

Tags: jquery, compression, tinymce, gzip

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to use the GZIP compressed version of TinyMCE with the jQuery plugin. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this post](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2006/07/13/compressed-javascript/) solve your question?

You just link to GZIPped version of JS file and use it as if it was not comperessed.

Comment: So easy, thank you. I actually rummaged through the documentation aimlessly and found instructions on loading the PHP file jQuery-style. It's amazing how disorganized a professional script like TinyMCE is when it comes to docs.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @John Yes, I know the lack of documentation is painful. Happy it helped.

Comment: John, would you mind posting the link to the solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same processes and thought I'd post my solution, although I'm sure that Tadeck's is correct.  I used the PHP compressor, but hopefully this approach works with the others as well.

First, install TinyMCE using the jQuery plugin and get that working.  My initialization code looked like this:

```
// Assign tinyMCE to any textarea with the tinymce class
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({

        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '/lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

});
```

You'll probably need to change script_url to point to wherever you installed tiny_mce. After you have that working, download the PHP compressor.  Upload the tiny_mce_gzip.php to the same folder where you installed tiny_mce.  For me it was /lib/tiny_mce.  Here's what my folder looked like after adding tiny_mce_gzip.php:

[image]

Next, modify the script_url in your jquery tinymce parameters to point to the php script instead of the tiny_mce.js file, like so:

```
// Assign tinyMCE to any textarea with the tinymce class
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({

        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '/lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php', /*<========== updated!*/

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
...etc...
```

And that's all I had to do. :-)

Hope this helps,
- Bret